# Client-side load balancing in gRPC

Tags: grpc, load-balancing, grpc-java

We are implementing our own client-side load balancing strategy without any proxies. Currently we have 10 servers in our backend and is creating one channel for each server and cache and reuse them. In order to improve the performance, we are considering something like route request based on how congested each server is (e.g. how many requests each server served / is serving right now) and route the request to the least congested one. Is there an easy way in gRPC to get those metadata?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is basically done by the existing WeightedRoundRobinLoadBalancer.  In that case, it is relying on the server to send a report of time spent / transaction so that as the server slows down it gets lower priority.  It is part of the XDS feature, so if you aren't using that then you couldn't use it directly, though you could use it as a model for creating your own.

Having the client know what work it has sent to the server is only useful if there is a single client.  You could have the servers periodically send a streamed message with their current "congestion state".

Comment: `least_request` is generally easier to use than `weighted_round_robin`. It doesn't require any coordination between the server and client, so if you can simply change `round_robin` to `least_request` and see if you like the different behavior. More info about least_request: https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/A48-xds-least-request-lb-policy.md